# OpenCL’s function clGetPlatformInfo runtime problem. Win10, VS2012

Tags: c++, runtime, opencl

My hardware are Intel Core I7 6700, 32 GB RAM, Nvidia GT1030. My Software are Windows 10 64bit, Visual Studio 2012 professional. I bought the book “OpenCL Parallel Programing Development Cookbook”. Unfortunately I have problems with compiled program. Program execution ends at line (first call of clGetPlatformInfo) `error = clGetPlatformInfo(id, param_name, 0, NULL, &paramSize);`

```
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "CL/cl.h"
#include "CL/cl_platform.h"
#include "malloc.h"
#include "resconsts.h"
 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
static ofstream fout ("log_main_cpp.txt");
 
typedef unsigned char Byte;
 
void displayPlatformInfo(cl_platform_id id, cl_platform_info param_name,
  const char* paramNameAsStr) 
{
  cl_int error = 0;
  size_t paramSize = 0;
  error = clGetPlatformInfo(id, param_name, 0, NULL, &paramSize);  
  char* moreInfo = (char*) malloc(paramSize);
  error = clGetPlatformInfo(id, param_name, paramSize, moreInfo, NULL);
  if (error != CL_SUCCESS)
    fout << "Unable to find any OpenCL Platform information";
  fout << "paramNameAsStr = " << paramNameAsStr << endl 
    << "moreInfo = " << moreInfo << endl; 
}
 
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
  LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) 
{
  cl_platform_id *platforms;
  cl_uint numOfPlatforms;
  cl_int error;
  error = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numOfPlatforms);
  if (error < 0) {
    fout << "Unable to find any OpenCL platforms" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  // Allocate memory for the number of installed platforms.
  // alloca(...) occupies some stack space but is auromatically freed on return.
  platforms = (cl_platform_id*) alloca (sizeof(cl_platform_id)*numOfPlatforms);
  fout << "Number of OpenCL platforms found: " << numOfPlatforms << endl;
  // We invoke the API 'clPlatformInfo' twice for each parameter we're trying 
  // to extract and we use the return value to create temporary data structures
  // (on the stack) to store the returned information on the second invocation.
  for (cl_uint i = 0; i < numOfPlatforms; i++) {
    displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE,
      "CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE");
    displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION,
      "CL_PLATFORM_VERSION");
    displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME,
      "CL_PLATFORM_NAME");
    displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR,
      "CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR");
    displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS,
      "CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS");
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Program was successfully compiled after adding “OpenCL.lib” in “Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies”.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: clGetPlatformInfo returns -32 (CL_INVALID_PLATFORM)

Comment: Then `malloc(paramSize)` is probably failing due to `paramSize` being uninitialised, you need to check the error code before continuing. Your main problem is presumably that you've not initialised `platforms` in `WinMain`

Answer (score 0):

You never populate `platforms` so using it is undefined behaviour:

```
error = clGetPlatformIDs(numOfPlatforms, platforms, nullptr);
```

You also need to check the result of `clGetPlatformInfo` before calling `malloc` on `paramSize`, if `clGetPlatformInfo` fails it might not have set `paramSize`.

`displayPlatformInfo` also leaks memory, it'd be safer and simpler to use `std::string`:

```
void displayPlatformInfo(cl_platform_id id, cl_platform_info param_name,
  const char* paramNameAsStr) 
{
  cl_int error = 0;
  size_t paramSize = 0;
  error = clGetPlatformInfo(id, param_name, 0, NULL, &paramSize);  
  if (error != CL_SUCCESS)
  {
    fout << "Unable to find any OpenCL Platform information";
    return;
  }
  std::string moreInfo(paramSize - 1);
  error = clGetPlatformInfo(id, param_name, paramSize, moreInfo.data(), NULL);
  if (error != CL_SUCCESS)
    fout << "Unable to find any OpenCL Platform information";
  else
    fout << "paramNameAsStr = " << paramNameAsStr << endl 
      << "moreInfo = " << moreInfo << endl; 
}
```